# When to specify "buffer size" in assembly strings and when not to?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I know 20 in `string DB 20, 'hello world'` is the buffer size but I can't understand what is it's purpose. For example, when declaring two strings such as:

```
string DB 20, 'hello world'
string2 DB 'hello world'
```

And comparing them, both seems to hold exactly the same data, except the first byte is skipped. But for all practical purposes they are the same. When is adding the buffer size useful and when is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the size of the buffer but the ASCII value of "Device Control 4" which will not print anything.  What you defined is the same as declaring that variable `string db 20,104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100`

In the "Old days" of DOS, some interupts expected the first byte of a string to be the length, are you programming for DOS?

Comment: thanks, I was sure it was the buffer size. I'm programming for Intel 8086. What is "Device Control 4" used for? I started removing it from string and didn't seem to cause any problems